# Expandable ListView with Drag and Drop feature

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to add drag and drop feature for Expandable ListView in Android? The drag and drop needs to be implemented for child items with in single group and also for reordering groups items also? Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you solve your problem  if extend this list and make it expandable.
Advanced RecyclerView has a lot of features

[DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView)

[Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview)

Comment: Is there any best practices library